# how to go about developing for blackberry 7.0 and lower

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to develop an app for blackberry 7.0 and earlier,
from the website i have downloaded the needed tools for BBOS for smartphones

- WebworksSDK
- Ripple
- Simulator (though i have a bb phone for testing)
- bbui.js

  I have also installed the sdk and ripples successfully
  The thing is when i open the bbui sample index page, it is blank on my browser, 
  is there anything else i have to configure on my PC am using (windows 7).
  how do i startup and get things running ?

Comment: in my opinion, if you develop apps for os <7 then use java based development tools. use native java tool.

Answer (score 0):

To get started with WebWorks development for BBOS, the best place to "get started" is the Getting Started page @ https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html

If you're seeing a blank screen in the browser when testing the bbUI.js sample(s) I'm guessing you may not have started Ripple's services yet before loading the sample?